# Datagridview Cell Click event error to get datagrid to textbox

Tags: c#

I used following code for get value of dataGridView to textbox when click a row. But when i click dataGridView column header to sort it shows an error.

```
        private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value != null)
            {
                dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Selected = true;
                txtID.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ID"].FormattedValue.ToString();
                txtTDate.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["TDate"].FormattedValue.ToString();
                txtBillNo.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["BillNo"].FormattedValue.ToString();
                txtTaka.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Taka"].FormattedValue.ToString();
                txtVat.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Vat"].FormattedValue.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
        }
    }
```

How to get rid of this error.[image]
[image]

Comment: `if (e.RowIndex == -1)
            {
                return;
            }`

Comment: I want to show message if no checkbox checked when click delete button. How can I solve the problem?